# How to ensure qRegisterMetaType is run when my shared library is loaded?

Tags: c++, initialization, shared-libraries, qt5

I've created a `QObject`-derived class that looks something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

        public:

            enum MyEnum 
            {
                Item1,
                Item2
            };

        Q_SIGNALS:

            void mySignal(MyEnum type);
    };
}
```

`MyEnum` needs to be registered with `qRegisterMetaType`.

Here's the twist: this class is contained in a shared library, and therefore I want to avoid instructing anyone using my library to call `qRegisterMetaType`. Instead, the `enum` should be registered as soon as the shared library is loaded.

Is there any way to do this? I need the solution to work with Qt 5 (I am not currently supporting Qt 4.x). Qt 5.1 introduces the [`QGlobalStatic`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qglobalstatic.html) class, but I need to maintain compatibility with Qt 5.0.

If I were to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, it would need to go outside of the namespace. It would look something like this:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum)
```

However, the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro would expand to the following call to `qRegisterMetaType`:

```
qRegisterMetaType< MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum >("MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum",
    reinterpret_cast< MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum *>(quintptr(-1)));
```

So the `enum` would be registered with the full namespace qualifiers but the signal would be registered as `mySignal(MyEnum)`. Therefore, the type `MyEnum` would not be registered with Qt since only `MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum` was registered.

Comment: Have you looked into [Q_ENUMS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#Q_ENUMS) at all? I can't seem to find at what point it adds the enum to the meta-object system (a part of the moc-magic I suppose), but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: @SethAnderson: That looks promising. I'll check it out.

Comment: @SethAnderson: I tried adding `Q_ENUMS`. Unfortunately, I get an error during runtime: `Don't know how to handle 'MyEnum', use qRegisterMetaType to register it.`

Comment: Random forum posts seem to suggest that both are needed. It seems that `Q_ENUMS` doesn't also register it with `QVariant`, which is required for queued connections. If worse comes to worst, it's not unprecedented to require the client binary to call an init method wherein you can call `qRegisterMetaType`.

Comment: Do you need it to be a "shared library" or can you turn it into a [plugin](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/plugins-howto.html#the-lower-level-api-extending-qt-applications)? A plugin will allow you to run some code (i.e. the plugin's instance constructor). Otherwise, a global should do the trick.